# PgAdmin: could not send data to server: Socket is not connected could not send SSL negotiation packet: Socket is not connected

Tags: postgresql

While opening query tool via pgadmin, i am getting this error on popup.

[could not send data to server: Socket is not connected  could not send SSL negotiation packet: Socket is not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgGNq.png)

Does any one know why this is happening.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

try changing your host connection to "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" it worked for me

Comment: If your local resolution makes `localhost` not resolve to `127.0.0.1`, you have a big problem on your hand as almost everything running out there is excepting this name resolution.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, `localhost` also resolves to the IPv6 loopback address `::1`, while postgres might be configured to listen on `127.0.0.1` only.

Comment: Thanks! This bug is ridiculous. I could see everything about my db but not the rows of tables.

Comment: @CharmingRobot, you're welcome, hahaha yes it is

Comment: This worked for me. The interesting this is 127.0.0.1 was assigned to Kubernetes when I enabled docker. Is this by design?

Comment: This also resolved my issue when working with a postgres server running in VS code development docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider that another app is using the socket. Or the postgres pg_hba.conf needs to be modified to allow non-local access.

Comment: Can you provide me the modifications needs to be done in the pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: Every situation has different details on IP address ranges and such. Please review this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

After that, please post again if you have questions.